# Java аргументы или что то вроде этого

Tags: java

В интернете нашел такие "аргументы" как: `||`, `&&`, `&`, `|`.

Объяснений к ним не было, но я так понял, что `&` это "и", а `|` это "или", а что тогда делают `||` и `&&` я так и не понял.

Comment: вообще, что это, написано **в любом учебнике** по Java. Не знаю как вам, а мне кажется самым логичным читать учебник, когда хочешь чему то научится ...

Comment: это не дубликат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простым языком это объясняется так: если **сокращённый** вариант `&&` проверяет первое условие и оно **не верно**, то второе условие не проверяется, так как общий результат уже точно будет `false`; аналогично если `||` проверяет первое условие и оно **верно**, то второе условие не проверяется, так как общий результат уже точно будет `true`. (`&` Логическое AND (И); `&&`    Сокращённое AND; `|`    Логическое OR (ИЛИ); `||`   Сокращённое OR).

Answer (score 7):

`& | ~ >> << >>> ^` - побитовые операторы *и, или, не, правый сдвиг, левый сдвиг, правый сдвиг без заполнения, исключающее и.*
`&& || !` - логические операторы *и, или, не*.

**Побитовые операторы** выполняют операции с битами;
 Например при применении оператора `~` к числу 11001101 (205) все биты инвертируются, и получится число 00110010 (-206).

**Логические операторы** выполняют логические операции с `true` или `false`;
Например возьмём такую строку кода: `System.out.print(!("".isEmpty()))`. Здесь, метод `isEmpty` вернет *true*, но при помощи оператора `!` результат инвертируется и соответственно в консоли появится *false*.

Также замечу что логические операторы могут быть заменены побитовыми, но не наоборот.

Answer (score 5):

**1-символные** операторы (`&` и `|`) - побитовые, они применяются *отдельно* к каждой паре битов *на одинаковой позиции*:

`0b101 & 0b110` есть `0b100`, и `0b101 | 0b110` есть `0b111`.

или

```
       101                         101
    &  110                      |  110
    ------                      ------
       100                         111
```

по таблицaм

```
  & | 0 | 1 |                  | | 0 | 1 |
  --+---+---+                  --+---+---+
  0 | 0 | 0 |                  0 | 0 | 1 |
  --+---+---+                  --+---+---+
  1 | 0 | 1 |                  1 | 1 | 1 |
```

---

**2-символные** операторы (`&&` и `||`) - это то, о чём вы говорите, *логические* операторы:

`(2 * 2 == 4) && (1 + 1 == 2)` есть `true`
`(2 * 2 == 7) && (1 + 1 == 2)` есть `false`
`(2 * 2 == 7) || (1 + 1 == 2)` есть `true`
`(2 * 2 == 7) || (1 + 1 == 9)` есть `false`

по подобным таблицам (где вместо `0` - `false`, вместо `1` - `true`, вместо `&` - `&&`, и вместо `|` - `||`):

```
  &&  | false | true  |           ||  | false | true |
------+-------+-------+         ------+-------+------+
false | false | false |         false | false | true |
------+-------+-------+         ------+-------+------+
true  | false | true  |         true  | true  | true |
```